# cosmos db graph api how to check if exist and update edge?

Tags: graph, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

Ho to check if edge already exist before create one with gremlin query? How to update existing edge instead of deleting and recreating?

Comment: Could you add a few more details? What's the criterion for an existing edge? An edge with a specific label between 2 specific vertices? Does it have to have specific properties? And what do you mean by "update an existing edge"? Just add / remove / change some of its properties?

Comment: ok, so easiest way to update edge property is to use query: g.E().has('anyProperty', 'propValue').property('propName', 'propValue')
Cosmos DB doesn't have fully implemented support for gremlin language. For now only some basic commands are acceptable.You can forget about dynamic values is queries etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're still looking for an answer; however, the simple answer is that Cosmos DB is somewhat limited in its Gremlin support. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/gremlin-support. The only way to update an edge as at the time of writing this answer is to delete and recreate the edge. That is true whether you're adding properties or updating them.

In terms of querying if the edge already exists, you can use `g.E('<xyz-id-guid>')` or `g.V('id', '<xyz-id-guid>', '<partition-key-property>', '<xyz-id>').outE('<edge-label>').hasId('<xyz-id-guid>')`. The `hasId()` part is optional but recommended as is the use of the partition key value. Both help performance.

Hope that helps.

Cheers,
Seb